# Apache Ignite autoscaling in AWS (linux)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ignite

Currently we host Apache Ignite node in AWS using Apache Ignite Image with 16 RAM.
We want to dynamically add new nodes while load on cache increases.
For this purpose we need to somehow trigger that node will run out of memory soon and we need to add additional node. Is there any way to track that?
I've tried to load cache with random data, cache failed with OutOfMemoryException when java process took over 30-40% of RAM.
Here is default-config.xml from {IGNITE_HOME}\config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="default"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="false"/>
                                                <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.s3.TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder">
                        <property name="awsCredentialsProvider" ref="aws.creds"/>
                        <property name="bucketName" value="dev-apache-ignite"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- AWS credentials. Provide your access key ID and secret access key. -->
    <bean id="aws.creds" class="com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="false" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Sorry if this question was alsready answered in documentation.
Is there any predefined guidelines to configure AWS autoscaling for ignite?

Comment: You've got 2 problems here, the first is you need to tune your Java memory settings if it is running out of memory with only 40% of RAM used. The second is you need to configure AWS auto-scaling when memory usage gets above a certain threshold. Is this running directly on AWS EC2? Or ECS on EC2? ECS on Fargate? EKS?

Answer (score 0):

Amount of RAM taken by JVM is not relevant. You will see IgniteOutOfMemoryException when you run out of data region - in your case, 10G.

You may divide `DataRegionMetrics.getOffheapUsedSize()` by data region size to understand how much runway do you have left.

Then you can probably use GridGain K8S Operator to scale your cluster:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator/how-tos

Comment: alamar, thank you for your answer. Is it possible to get these data metrics from .NET this client? Haven't found appropriate methods in IIgniteClient (Apache.Ignote.Core 2.10.0)

Comment: You can probably run a compute task which will run some code which will get this metric for you. These metrics are supposed to be collected on the server side. Maybe also via system views.